# DOMAIN registration

Tags: domain, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I was planning to register a site domain like "site.io.us", but the problem is that famous registrant doesn't allows more then 1 "." char in their search inputs.

So how or where can i check or register domains like this?

I mean, del.icio.us was registerd why does i can't do the same with similar domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you only have to register the TLD eg: del.icio.us only has icio.us registered. the del is just a subdomain from icio.us

Hopes this clearfies your question a bit.

Comment: `icio.us` is a SLD (second level domain), `us` is the TLD (Top Level Domain)